# Thread starvation when using dispatch_semaphore_wait inside dispatch queue?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

If I'm using `dispatch_semaphore_wait` inside a dispatch queue, could this starve my dispatch queue of threads if many threads are blocked on `dispatch_semaphore_wait`?

```
parallelDownloadsSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(4);

[...]

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
    dispatch_semaphore_wait([self parallelDownloadsSemaphore], DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    // perform lengthy download
    dispatch_semaphore_signal([self parallelDownloadsSemaphore]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You assumption is, as far as I know, right. The call of `dispatch_semaphore_wait` blocks the executing thread. I had this problem in a similar situation and figured out, that a concurrent queue two threads for each core creates (and for each priority). I'm not hundred percent sure if was 2 * cpu cores or 1 * cpu cores, but the number of threads for a concurrent queue is limited.

Comment: So you say, blocked threads don't get returned to the thread pool and therefore there is a rather big risk of running out of threads, if many threads are blocked. And in general there is only one thread available per CPU core on the standard queues? Does anyone have a reference to the documentation to support this?

Comment: With the blocking of the thread I'm pretty sure and you should always avoid this. That the number of threads per concurrent queue is somehow limited to the number of CPUs was just an observation I did. But with this I'm not absolutely sure. I try to find some references.